# Вопросы и ответы, которые перестанут быть актуальными через некоторое время

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Как пример, на данный момент у многих проблемы с доступностью ресурсов из-за действий РКН:

1. [Нет соединения с download.mono-project.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/825237/15479).
2. [Не доходят запросы к удалённому серверу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/825086/15479).

Но подобные вопросы (которые актуальны только на определённый промежуток времени) периодически появляются. Что в таких случаях делать? Через пару месяцев такие вопросы уже будут бесполезны для сообщества.

Comment: Через год все эти вопросы будут дубликатами к одному с правильным ответом: "Не нужно пользоваться интернетом напрямую, нужно настроить соединение через ГосVPN с белым списком доступных ресурсов"

Comment: @vp_arth или так "Ух ты, в РФ ещё остались программисты!"

Comment: В любом случае стоит поменьше думать о "сообществе" и побольше о конкретном человеке с его конкретным вопросом

Comment: Обсуждение ещё не началось, а вопросы уже кто-то удалил( .

Comment: @СашаЧерных я свой сам удалил )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо сделать один эталонный вопрос с ответом и закрывать как дубликаты, вероятно.